# Image downloaded from AWS S3 is not opening correctly in any viewer

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I created a simple api using API Gateway to upload images to my S3 bucket.

[image]

[image]

And when i try to upload a jpeg file using curl, its getting uploaded into S3.

`curl --request PUT -H "Content-Type: image/jpeg" --data-binary "@s.jpeg" https://173xxxxxxxf.execute-api.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/Test/memxxxx/s.jpeg`

But I am noticing multiple issues here

1. the file size is almost doubled(85KB original size, 153KB in S3)
2. If I download the file from S3, I am not able to view the image in any default image viewer.

If I upload the same image to S3 using drag & drop and then download it, it works without any issues.

What's the best way to handle it properly( I assume the issue is with the header type)

Edit:

I also tried to set the content as base64 encoded string and still facing the same issue

```
const https = require("https");
var fs = require("fs");

var data = base64_encode("filename.jpg");

const options = {
  hostname: "173ixxxxxxf.execute-api.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com",
  port: 443,
  path: "/Test/xxxx/filename.jpeg",
  method: "PUT",
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "image/jpg",
    "Content-Length": data.length,
  },
};

const req = https.request(options, (res) => {
  console.log(`statusCode: ${res.statusCode}`);
  res.on("data", (d) => {
    process.stdout.write(d);
  });
});

req.on("error", (error) => {
  console.error(error);
});

req.write(data);
req.end();

function base64_encode(file) {
  // read binary data
  var bitmap = fs.readFileSync(file);
  // convert binary data to base64 encoded string
  return new Buffer(bitmap).toString("base64");
}
```

Comment: The image data can be encoded as `base64`. Did you check for that?

Comment: any lambda code? indeed the request payload may or may not be base64 encoded, but should be handled by the code

Comment: @Marcin I tried with base64 as well. Still the same. Added the details to question as well